# I can't validate min time in html form (datetime-local)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-formhandler

I try to validate min and max time in datetlime-local html form. min date and max date are works fine. but time is not working.

`<input type="datetime-local" name="dateOfShedule" id="dateOfShedule" min='2022-11-01T05:26:00' max='2022-11-30T05:26:00'/>`

[image]